# Cakephp 3 : Json render View not working

Tags: php, ajax, json, cakephp

I've been trying to setup an Ajax Call in Cakephp 3.0.11.
I've followed the explanation here : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Json enabled in routing (but i'm not really sure that's usefull) :

```
$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'html']);
```

I've setup my exemple in controller :

```
$returnObject = new ObjectReturn();
$this->set('returnObject', $returnObject);
$this->set('_serialize', ['returnObject']);
```

But when I make my ajax call, I've got :

```
{
    "message": "Template file \Pages\\score.ctp\ is missing.",
    "url": "\/pages\/score",
    "code": 500
}
```

If I create the page, he juste render me some html, with default.ctp as a layout. What's wrong here ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you load the `RequestHandlerComponent` in your controller as explained [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#enabling-data-views-in-your-application)?

Comment: And b.t.w, to enable `json` view using extensions and request handling, your url needs to use the `.json` extension, such as `/pages/score.json`.

Comment: Hello 
Thanks for the answer. I've upgraded to the last version of Cake, and now it works. Maybe a bug have been correct. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: This worked when you upgraded because of the following: `As of 3.1.0 AppController, in the application skeleton automatically adds '_serialize' => true to all XML/JSON requests. You will need to remove this code from the beforeRender callback if you want to use view files.` from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-template-files

Answer (score 9):

If you'd like to force every response (except errors) to JSON (and skip templates) you can put this code in your AppController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}

public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    $this->response->type('application/json');
    $this->set('_serialize', true);
}
```

This loads the RequestHandlerComponent, forces the render to JSON, forces the response type to JSON, and skips using templates.

More in the manual here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was driving crazy to output json!! Seems like setting `$this->set('_serialize', $vars);` is not enough!!

Tip: works also for CakePHP 2!

Answer (score 8):

To achieve a json/xml render view in your cakephp 3 application, you need to edit two file in your application

1. AppController.php

Edit initialize function to look like this

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');/*This line loads the required RequestHandler Component*/
}
```

2. routes.php (under your config folder)

Edit Router::scope() to look like this

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'ajax']);
    /*Other route definitions as already existing*/
}
```

You may now load a json view by adding .json or xml by adding .xml to the link that normally loads your html.

Cheers